# Why am I getting the addresses of the array instead of the values (two-dimensional array)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

> ```
>   5 import java.util.*;
>   6 
>   7 class Matrix {
>   8     // declare the member field
>   9     private int[][] matrix;
>  10 
>  12     public Matrix(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
>  13         matrix = new int[2][2];
>  14         matrix[0][0] = a;
>  15         matrix[0][1] = b;
>  16         matrix[1][0] = c;
>  17         matrix[1][1] = d;
>  18     }
>  19     // identity matrix
>  20     public Matrix(char i) {
>  21         matrix = new int[2][2];
>  22         matrix[0][0] = 1;
>  23         matrix[0][1] = 0;
>  24         matrix[1][0] = 1;
>  25         matrix[1][1] = 0;
>  26     }
>  27 
>  29     public int[][] toPow(int n, int[][] matrix) {
>  30         if (n == 1)
>  31             return matrix;
>  32         else {
>  33             int[][] temp = matrix;
>  34             for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
>  35                 for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
>  36                     temp[i][j] += matrix[i][j] * this.matrix[j][i];
>  37                 }
>  38             }
>  39             return toPow(n - 1, temp);
>  40         }
>  41     }
>  42     public int[][] toPow(int n) {
>  43         return toPow(n, this.matrix);
>  44     }
>  45 }
>  46 
>  47 class Maths {
>  48 
>  49     public static void main(String[] args) {
>  55         Matrix m = new Matrix(1,2,3,4);
>  56         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.toPow(2)));
>  57         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[][] {{1,2},{3,4}}));
>  58     }
>  59 }
> ```

Arrays.toString(Array) should be printing out the contents of the array when called. But when I tried to print the array in the last 2 lines of the code, I get the addresses instead of the content. Can anyone please help me understand why that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the results of calling `toString()` on each element of your *top* array. But each element is itself an array. Use [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m.toPow(2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.toString()` only works for one-dimensional arrays. Try iterating over the rows of the array and using `Arrays.toString()` on each row separately.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.toString (int[]) supports array (one-dimension), not matrices (two + dimension)

Answer (score 0):

You can call Arrays.toString() for each line of the matrix or Arrays.deepToString().

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test().run();
    }

    private void run() {
       int[] v = { 1, 2, 3 };
       int[][] m = { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };
       System.out.println("Printing the array: ");
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
       System.out.println("Printing the line addresses: ");
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));

       System.out.println("Priting the matrix: ");
       for (int[] l : m) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
        }  

        System.out.println("Priting the matrix (deepToString): ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Printing the array: 
[1, 2, 3]
Printing the line addresses: 
[[I@3182f0db, [I@b92d342, [I@546b97fd]
Priting the matrix: 
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
Priting the matrix (deepToString): 
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```